# Php Mode keep show this error. #16330

Tags: spacemacs

Hello i am on spacemacs and facing a error keep pop up and i have no idea why, may someone help me look into it ?

```
ac-php: Unable to resolve project root
Company: An error occurred in auto-begin
Company: backend (company-ac-php-backend company-phpactor :with company-yasnippet) error "Wrong type argument: stringp, nil" with args (candidates daadaada)
ac-php: Unable to resolve project root
eldoc error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing to trigger the error? We'll need a complete recipe from starting Emacs to when you get the error with all the steps in-between.

Comment: Actually i just put php in .dotspacemacs-configuration-layers to install it, in the installing php layer there is a error came out and i found out is phpcbf is not available anymore, so i put phpcbf in dotspacemacs-excluded-packages to prevent it the package include. but now every time i open a php file this error cameout.

Comment: This description should be placed in the question: it is useful information for someone trying to reproduce the problem, so you should  not hide it in a comment (comments are for asking clarifying questions of you, but you should put all the relevant details in the questions itself - comments are not searchable and they can be deleted).